# How to find length of the sequence in a list using python [with Duplicates]?

Tags: python

I am trying with below code.

```
from itertools import groupby

range_mod = ['P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'P', 'P', 'P']

print(dict((i,len(list(j))) for i, j in groupby(range_mod)))
```

**Note: Output need not be in Dict**

**Actual Output:**

```
{'P': 3, 'N': 4}
```

**Expected output: I am aware Dictionary doesn't allow duplicate keys. So looking for other options**

```
{'P': 4, 'N': 4, 'P' : 3}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you getting the `P` counts?

Comment: Since we have 2 sets of 'P' , dictionary is getting override so the value for 'P' is showing as '3'. I will modify my expected output. Thanks

Comment: Typo on the P counts? In any case, you might be best off getting a list like [('P',4), ('N',4)...]

Comment: Looks like my question is Duplicate. But I couldn't find this question while searching. Anyway thanks everyone. Problem is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
>>> lengths=[]
>>> for k, g in groupby(range_mod):
...    lengths.append({k:len(list(g))})
... 
>>> lengths
[{'P': 4}, {'N': 4}, {'P': 3}]
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
>>> [{k:len(list(g))} for k, g in groupby(range_mod)]
[{'P': 4}, {'N': 4}, {'P': 3}]
```

Or tuples:

```
>>> [(k,len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(range_mod)]
[('P', 4), ('N', 4), ('P', 3)]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> print(list((i,len(list(j))) for i, j in groupby(range_mod)))
[('P', 4), ('N', 4), ('P', 3)]
```

How about this? ^

Comment: Wow. This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks Swakeert :)

Comment: Can become a tiny bit prettier by using list comprehension instead of the outer call to `list`:     `print([(i, len(list(j))) for i, j in groupby(range_mod)])`. Nice answer!